# Using siunitx when there are percentage symbols

Tags: formatting, siunitx

is there a way I could align the comma signal on the numbers even with the `%` sign?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} 
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} 
\usepackage[vmargin=3cm, hmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[group-separator={.},
            group-four-digits,
            output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\caption{Estat\'{i}sticas - Escolaridade e Cor -2016} 
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llll}
  \toprule
  & Controle & Tratado & Total \\ 
  \midrule
Cor & - & - & - \\
\hspace{4mm} Brancos & 56.1\% & 57.2\% & 56.3\% \\ 
\hspace{4mm}  Amarelos e Ind\'{i}genas & 0.7\% & 0.8\% & 0.7\% \\ 
 \hspace{4mm} Pretos e Pardos & 43.2\% & 42.0\% & 43.0\% \\ 
  \midrule
  Escolaridade & - & - & - \\
 \hspace{4mm} At\'{e} Ensino Fundamental incompleto & 18.5\% & 10.3\% & 17.0\% \\ 
 \hspace{4mm} At\'{e} Ensino M\'{e}dio incompleto & 18.1\% & 15.1\% & 17.5\% \\ 
 \hspace{4mm} At\'{e} Ensino Superior incompleto & 40.2\% & 39.8\% & 40.1\% \\ 
 \hspace{4mm} Ensino Superior completo & 23.2\% & 34.8\% & 25.4\% \\ 
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea to put the % sign on each number; better to put it in the column heading.

You've loaded `siunitx` but you're not using its `S` column type for the numbers.  So here's a modified version of your table. I've made a small shorthand `\mc` to save some typing for the column headings.

I've also changed your accented characters into proper accented characters in the source. Since you are loading `inputenc` with `[utf8]` there's no need to use macros for accents.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} 
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} 
\usepackage[vmargin=3cm, hmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[group-separator={.},
            group-four-digits,
            output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\newcommand\mc{\multicolumn{1}{c}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\caption{Estatísticas - Escolaridade e Cor -- 2016} 
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lSSS}
  \toprule
  & \mc{Controle} & \mc{Tratado} & \mc{Total} \\ 
  & \mc{\%} & \mc{\%} & \mc{\%}\\
  \midrule
Cor &  \\
\hspace{4mm} Brancos & 56.1 & 57.2 & 56.3 \\ 
\hspace{4mm}  Amarelos e Indígenas & 0.7 & 0.8 & 0.7 \\ 
 \hspace{4mm} Pretos e Pardos & 43.2 & 42.0 & 43.0 \\ 
  \midrule
  Escolaridade &  \\
 \hspace{4mm} Até Ensino Fundamental incompleto & 18.5 & 10.3 & 17.0 \\ 
 \hspace{4mm} Até Ensino Médio incompleto & 18.1 & 15.1 & 17.5 \\ 
 \hspace{4mm} Até Ensino Superior incompleto & 40.2 & 39.8 & 40.1 \\ 
 \hspace{4mm} Ensino Superior completo & 23.2 & 34.8 & 25.4 \\ 
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]